# How capture the facebook fbclid and forward it to the client with a button click

Tags: facebook, url

We're testing a new tracking method and want to pass the Facebook fbclid on to the client.
Just to be clear...

1. The user clicks the Facebook ad,
2. They land on our page
3. They click a button and are taken to the client

How can we capture the fbclid and forward it on to the client when the user clicks the button on our page?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code. Which included adding a class to the link. Will check to see if it works.

```
         let anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("marketingAnchor")
Array.from(anchors).forEach(element => {
    let currentURL = new URL(window.location.href)
    let AnchorHref = element.getAttribute('href')
    let tmpURLObj = new URL(AnchorHref)
    let fbclidParam = currentURL.searchParams.get("fbclid")

    if (AnchorHref == null || fbclidParam == null) return;

    tmpURLObj.searchParams.set('fbclid', fbclidParam);
    element.setAttribute('href', tmpURLObj.href)
});</script>
```